# Работа с SOAP с помощью retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, soap

Возможно ли работать с SOAP при помощи retrofit?

Как максимально упростить работу?

Comment: Вроде как нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться готовой библиотекой.

http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html

Comment: Спасибо.
Велосипеды разные бывают. retrofit в пользование намного проще чем  использовать ksoap, http клиенты и создавать много AsyncTask`ов и т.п.

Comment: Вы сравниваете несравнимое. Retrofit - это менеджер, который запускает HTTP client, а на результат натравливает JSON/XML parser. SOAP - это развесистый протокол. Да, он использует XML и HTTP, да, для этого можно использовать Retrofit. Но самый главный вопрос - кто будет программировать этот монстрообразный протокол?

Comment: Ну и вдогонку. Не надо использовать для сложных протоколов AsyncTask. Вообще их не надо использовать. Делайте отдельную подсистему, в ней реализуйте взаимодействие с сервером. Делайте к ней интерфейс внутри приложения, хоть на колбэках, хоть на Rx.